# C++ N-last added items container

Tags: c++, stl

I try to find optimal data structure for next simple task: class which keeps N last added item values in built-in container. If object obtain N+1 item it should be added at the end of the container and first item should be removed from it. It like a simple queue, but class should have a method GetAverage, and other methods which must have access to every item. Unfortunately, std::queue doesn't have methods *begin* and *end* for this purpose.

It's a part of simple class interface:

```
class StatItem final
{
    static int ITEMS_LIMIT;

public:
    StatItem() = default;
    ~StatItem() = default;

    void Reset();
    void Insert(int val);

    int  GetAverage() const;

private:
    std::queue<int> _items;
};
```

And part of desired implementation:

```
void StatItem::Reset()
{
    std::queue<int> empty;
    std::swap(_items, empty);
}

void StatItem::Insert(int val)
{
    _items.push(val);
    if (_items.size() == ITEMS_LIMIT)
    {
        _items.pop();
    }
}

int StatItem::GetAverage() const
{
    const size_t itemCount{ _items.size() };
    if (itemCount == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    const int sum = std::accumulate(_items.begin(), _items.end(), 0); // Error. std::queue doesn't have this methods
    return sum / itemCount;
}
```

Any ideas?

I'm not sure about std::deque. Does it work effective and should I use it for this task or something different?

P.S.: ITEMS_LIMIT in my case about 100-500 items

Comment: std::deque will suffice. Also you can find the average of all items in constant time after finding the average of first N items. Trick is when you pop an element, subtract it's value from the current total and add the value of the new element which is to be pushed in to the current total. Total items will remain N.

Comment: You can use `std::deque` and maintain sum at each insertion and removal of item.

Comment: Seems you want a circular buffer.

Comment: @Jarod42 now it seems I can use simple std::array with additional index in which position I should change value

Comment: [Boost circular buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: if you don't want to use boost or keep track of the average when inserting: `std::list` has a `push/pop_front` and `push/pop_back`.

Comment: Specifically because you have a limit on the number of items, it seems like you should use a `std::vector` or `std::array`, and keep track of the number of items and current insert position. It would be faster than a `std::list`, and probably a `std::deque`. Especially with less than 500 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you're looking for is a circular buffer. There is an implementation in the Boost library, however in this situation since it doesn't seem you need to remove items you can easily implement one using a `std::vector` or `std::array`.

You will need to keep track of the number of elements in the vector so far so that you can average correctly until you reach the element limit, and also the current insertion index which should just wrap when you reach that limit.

Using an array or vector will allow you to benefit from having a fixed element limit, as the elements will be stored in a single block of memory (good for fast memory access), and with both data structures you can make space for all elements you need on construction.

If you choose to use a `std::vector`, make sure to use the 'fill' constructor (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), which will allow you to create the right number of elements from the beginning and avoid any extra allocations.

Comment: Thanks for answer and tips. Eventually I have implemented it on std::array with additional index variable. And thanks for circular buffer tip, I haven’t known about it before